# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu on navbar toggle issue with last link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar dropdown menu that when it's on toggle mode ( mobile sized browser ) the link directly after the dropdown is not moving below the dropdown links. I am attaching a screenshot this is hard to describe. News is a main link like EVENTS.

### SCREEN SHOT

[image: Menu]

### HTML

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-header-full">
        <div class="container">





                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="header-full-title img-responsive">
                        <img src="~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>

                    @*<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>*@
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">


                    <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">OUR STORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">VISIT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">DIRECTORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">CONDOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">APARTMENTS</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="navStyle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EVENTS</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownMTC pull-left">
                                <li><a href="#">YOGA ROCKS THE PARK</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">MONDAY NIGHT MOVIES</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HORSES OF HONOR</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">THURSDAY IN THE PARK</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">EVENT SHUTTLE</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HOLIDAY LIGHTS FESTIVAL</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">NEWS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

### CSS

```
  .navStyle{

   color:white;
   padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
   margin: 0px;
   text-decoration:none;

  }

   .dropDownMTC{

    background-color:#00306a;
opacity: 0.9;
color: #bfd300;
left: 0;
float: right;
min-width: 250px;
padding: 10px 0;
margin: 0px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: right;
list-style: none;

 }
```

Comment: Does the issue happen without the pull-left?  Also, what's in the navStyle & dropDownMTC classes of your CSS?

Comment: Yeah I tried pull right and it still happens. I'll edit my post and add those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the pull-* class you're adding that's giving you problems.  As of Bootstrap 3.1.0 it's been deprecated, and the documentation suggests using dropdown-menu-left:

[Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment)

I checked Bootstrap's CSS for 3.3.6, and pull-left is styled as:

```
.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Which I'm guessing is why the rest of your menu is wrapping around it.  I copied your code into a Bootply, and replaced pull-left with dropdown-menu-left, and I believe it's giving us the intended results:

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/yH4HY6JIlK#)

Remember to hit the "Mobile View" button to run the bootply, pictured here:
[image]

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks for the help.